# Generate the private and public keys using the Diffie-Hellman parameters (‘p’ and ‘g’). The result is ‘Pub_key’and ‘Priv_key’ (1024-bit/128 bytes)

Tags: openssl, openssl-net

I have a documentation where I need to create two key pairs PUBLIC and PRIVATE using diffie-hellman parameters 'p' and 'g'. my issue how should pass the parameter 'p'?

Answer (score 1):

The modulus p is public so you can just send it over an unencrypted channel.